# Problema ao importar uma classe de outra pasta e usa-la. (Python)

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, importação

Eu estou ficando maluco aqui. Eu estou enfrentando um problema que deveria ter sido resolvido pela lógica já. O problema é esse:

Eu tenho duas pastas:

- novapasta/
- novapasta/classes

Na primeira pasta existe um arquivo:

- novapasta/main.py

Na segunda pasta, existe dois arquivos:

- novapasta/classes/classPrint.py
- novapasta/classes/classGerar.py

A lógica é a seguinte:

1. Eu abro o main.
2. O main importa a classe *classPrint*
3. A classe *classPrint* importa a classe *classGerar*

Até ai tudo bem. No arquivo main.py está o seguinte:

```
    from classes import classPrint
    objeto = classPrint.printar()
    print(objeto.b)
```

No arquivo classPrint está esse código:

```
    import classGerar
    objeto = classGerar.Gerar()
    class printar():
        b = objeto.a
```

O problema é que a classPrint não consegue importar a classeGerar. As duas classes estão na mesma pasta. Mas, uma não consegue importar a outra.

obs: Se eu colocar a main.py na mesma pasta das classes. A main funciona corretamente.

Alguém já enfrentou esse problema e conhece a solução?

Comment: Por enquanto, eu vou deixar tudo na mesma pasta e criar um atalho da main. Eu queria resolver esse problema para ter mais organização do código. Mas, está osso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A solução é a seguinte:
>
> 1. criar uma pasta chamada pastaGerar e colocar o classGerar.py dentro
>      dela.
> 2. no arquivo classPrint trocar a primeira linha por: "from .pastaGerar 
>      import classGerar"
>
> Esse bendito . antes da pastaGerar faz muita diferença. Eu só não
>   entendo porque eu não posso colocar essas classes todas na mesma
>   pasta.

Encontrei uma solução melhor. Ir na classPrint.py e substituir "import classGerar
" por "from . import classGerar"

Não precisa nem criar uma subpasta para a classGerar. É só mudar esse linha.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do diretório classes crie um arquivo chamado "__init__.py" com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
from classPrint import printar
```

Isto identificará ao Python que o diretório classes possui uma estrura de módulos e daí você poderá utilizar o `from classes import classPrint` dentro de "main.py".

Comment: Tentei: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classPrint'

Comment: O arquivo \_\_init\_\_.py está dentro do diretório "classes"?

Comment: Resolvi o problema.

Comment: É legal dizer que o `__init__.py` só é necessário até Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Temos a seguinte organização:

```
-main.py
--primeiro_nivel_de_pasta
  -minha_classe_dentro_do_primeiro_nivel_de_pasta.py
   -segundo_nivel_de_pasta
      -minha_classe_dentro_do_segundo_nivel_de_pasta.py
```

**Para a main.py acessar tanto o primeiro nivel** de pasta usei:

```
from primeiro_nivel_de_pasta import minha_classe_dentro_do_primeiro_nivel_de_pasta.py
```

Dai basta instanciar a classe e usufruir dela.

**Para a main.py acessar o segundo nivel de pasta usei:**

```
from primeiro_nivel_de_pasta import minha_classe_dentro_do_primeiro_nivel_de_pasta.py
```

**Para a minha_classe_dentro_do_primeiro_nivel_de_pasta.py acessar a classe minha_classe_dentro_do_segundo_nivel_de_pasta.py usei:**

```
from .segundo_nivel_de_pasta import minha_classe_dentro_do_segundo_nivel_de_pasta.py
```

Portanto, executei dessa maneira e deu super certo. \o/